# Is there a way to use join with OData in Dynamics CRM API?

Tags: c#, rest, api, dynamics-crm, postman

Is there a way to turn this code into a CRM Dynamics API request?

```
var t = (from contact in lServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
             join account in lServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on contact["parentcustomerid"] equals account["accountid"]
             where contact[key].Equals(value) && contact["statuscode"].Equals(1)
             select new
             {
                 AccountID = !account.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : account["accountid"],
                 AccountNumber = !account.Contains("accountnumber") ? string.Empty : account["accountnumber"],
                 AccountR3 = !account.Contains("new_r3number") ? string.Empty : account["new_r3number"]
             });
```

Well, i read this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/retrieve-related-entities-query) and i didn't quite understand how it works.

The idea is to make a request at the postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this should do the trick:

`https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$select=contactid,fullname,_parentcustomerid_value&$expand=parentcustomerid_account($select=accountid,accountnumber,name,new_r3number)`

In this case it looks like you can get by with an OData query, but if you ever run up against the WebAPI's OData limitations, you can [submit a FetchXML query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/retrieve-and-execute-predefined-queries#use-custom-fetchxml).

When building WebAPI queries, [Jason Lattimer's REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) can be indispensible.

And, in your original code it might be worth considering using the [GetAttributeValue](https://www.crmanswers.net/2015/04/getattributevalue-demystified.html) method.

Comment: Thanks mate. You opened my mind to fetchXML, although I don't need to use it, it was really nice to know about this feature. Much appreciated.